# how to authenticate flutter app from an on premise active directory?

Tags: android

I have a requirement to authenticate my flutter app from the on premise active directory. I tried the oauth2_client package for flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2_client), registered a dummy application on my personal account and authentication worked. The problem is that this package works only for azure AD, because we need to mention the tenant id and client which is not accessible to me on the on premise AD. I am very new with microsoft services, if someone could please reply with some pointers that would be life saving for me.